# PHP and MySQL Post Count Code

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

I have a PHP Micro-Blogging Website which is Star Trek-themed. What I would like to do is have it where if a user posts 200 messages, then a certain image appears, and same again when someone posts 300 images and it increments so on.

I know I'll need to have some kind of MySQL involvement, but I'm unsure how I should do this.

My website is: [www.thedatanetwork.co.uk](http://www.thedatanetwork.co.uk)

Comment: You look up your database, get the post count and if post count is greater than the amount you display the image. Now when you hit a programming problem with your code, show us the code and we can help

Answer (score 0):

Steps to be followed:
1.) define post count variable for user under user_info table and same as on php file
2.) increment that count whenever user posts, use update statement to update database then check-

```
if(user_post_count==200)
{
echo "your image url";
}
else
if(user_post_count==300)
{
echo "image url 2";
}

else
{
//move on to something else
}
```

just use basic mysql update commands in php query and you'll get what you want !!!!!

Comment: That's a great code, now how would I add the image to a certain area? Could I have something like {$rankimage} to place within the code?

Comment: I'm not great with MySQL. Could you write your explanation in more step by step detail please. If you need any of my code, then please ask.